# Call to undefined method CI_Loader::section() in codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

Currently I'm trying to write an AJAX script under my views folder in codeigniter. for this I have used `<?= $this->section('scripts')?>` to create a script inside the php file. But doing so gives me Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Loader::section(). Here is my full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CodeIgniter MVC Basics</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method='post' action="index">
    <h1>Customer Details</h1>

    <input type="date" name="startDate"/>
    <input type="date" name="endDate"/>
    <select name="status">
        <option>Draft</option>
        <option>Unpublish</option>
        <option>Let</option>
    </select>
    <br/><br/>
    <button type="button" class="alertbox" name="alertbox">alertbox</button>    

    </form>
</body>
</html>

<?= $this->section('scripts')?>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click', '.alertbox', function(){
            alert("Hello world");
        });
    });
</script>
<?= $this->endsection()?>
```

I want it so that whenever the button is clicked, there should be an alert popup in the screen.

**EDIT** I am loading the view from my controller like this:

```
$this->load->view('crm/test');
```

The following is the error:

[image]

Comment: How are you loading the view, I mean what does the controller look like?

Comment: @Don'tPanic could you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69446003/fetching-data-between-a-particular-date-range-and-filtering-by-dropdown-in-codei

Comment: I edited your question and added the relevant code - your question needs to include all the relevant info, *here*, not spread between other questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
$this->load->view('crm/test');
```

is how you [load a view in Codeigniter 3](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/views.html).

This code:

```
<?= $this->section('scripts')?>
...
<?= $this->endsection()?>
```

is using [layouts, from Codeigniter 4](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/outgoing/view_layouts.html).  So it looks like you're using CI4, but as [shown on that layouts page](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/outgoing/view_layouts.html#id3), and in [the main views documentation](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/outgoing/views.html#displaying-a-view), the way to render and display a view in CI4 is different:

```
echo view('crm/test');
```

Comment: Hey, could you also checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69450553/retrieving-number-of-rows-with-a-particular-value-after-filtering-query-through