# Retrieving number of rows with a particular value after filtering query through date picker

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Currently I'm using CodeIgniter to retrieve my data in a particular timeframe. All these entries have a status. I want to group all the entries that have the same status and display it in thier respective headings. Currently this is my model class where I have the following entry to return all the entries in a particular date range:

```
public function get_records($st_date,$end_date){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('crm_listings');
        $this->db->where('(added_date BETWEEN "' . $st_date . '" AND "' . $end_date . '")');
        
        echo $this->db->count_all_results();
     }
```

And my controller class:

```
function fetch_status(){
            $output ='';
            $startDate = '';
            $endDate = '';
            $this->load->model('crm/user_model');
  
            if($this->input->post('startDate')){
              $startDate = $this->input->post('startDate');
            }
            if($this->input->post('endDate')){
               $endDate = $this->input->post('endDate');
             }
            $data = $this->user_model->fetch_date($startDate,$endDate);
            
            $output .= '
              <div class="table-responsive">
                 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <tr>
                    <th>Draft</th>
                    <th>Unpublish</th>
                    <th>Publish</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                    <th>Unlisted</th>
                    <th>Sold</th>
                    <th>Let</th>
                    </tr>
              ';
           if($data->num_rows() > 0)
           {
            foreach($data->result() as $row)
            {
            $output .= '
               <tr>
                  //Dont know what to put in here
               </tr>
            ';
            }
           }
           else
           {
              $output .= '<tr>
                 <td colspan="7">No Data Found</td>
                 </tr>';
           }
           $output .= '</table>';
           echo $output;
           }
```

I have tried using the following command in my phpmyadmin which is giving me the output that I want, but I don't know how to make the query in codeigniter.

```
SELECT sum(case when status = 'D' then 1 else 0 end) AS Draft,
    sum(case when status = 'L' then 1 else 0 end) AS Let,
    id FROM `crm_listings`  
WHERE added_date BETWEEN '2021-09-24' AND '2021-09-28' ORDER BY `added_date` DESC
```

Here the dates have to be replaced with $startDate and $endDate.

Comment: please read the documents: [Query Builder Class](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html), jump to *$this->db->select()* section as well please read here: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?#CI_DB_query_builder::select

Answer (score 0):

```php
$sql = "SELECT
            sum(case when status = 'D' then 1 else 0 end) AS Draft,
            sum(case when status = 'L' then 1 else 0 end) AS Let,
            id
        FROM `crm_listings`  
        WHERE added_date BETWEEN '" . $st_date . "' AND '".$end_date."'
        ORDER BY `added_date` DESC";
$response = count($this->db->query($sql));
echo $response;
```

OR

```php
echo $response->num_rows();
```